# Arrow right hidden at the back of main div

Tags: html, css

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/u2Lbx4kc/)

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
            <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">1</a>
                </li>
                <li class="active arrow_box">
                    <a href="#">2</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">
            Example content with tabs at top
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.sidebar {
  display: none; }
  @media (min-width: 50em) {
    .sidebar {
      position: fixed;
      top: 30px;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      z-index: 1000;
      display: block;
      padding: 20px 0;
      margin-right: 20px;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #E5E5E5; } }

.nav-sidebar > li > a {
  color: #262626;
  font-size: 16pxpx;
  padding: 24px 20px 24px 50px; }

.nav-sidebar > .active > a,
.nav-sidebar > .active > a:hover,
.nav-sidebar > .active > a:focus {
  color: #30C4A3;
  background-color: #333;
 }

.nav-sidebar > li.active a:after {
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
  border-left: 10px solid re;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -13px;
  width: 0px;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: -10px;
  z-index: 90000; }

.main {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 1024px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  z-index: 0; }
  @media (min-width: 50em) {
    .main {
      padding-right: 40px;
      padding-left: 40px; } 
}

.arrow_box {
  background: #595959;
}

.arrow_box:after {
  left: 100%;
  top: 70%;
  border: solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  border-color: rgba(89, 89, 89, 0);
  border-left-color: #595959;
  border-width: 15px;
  margin-top: -30px;
  z-index: 4000;
}
```

Used Bootstrap Dashboard template example.

Tried omitting overflow-x but the scroll appeared and arrow could be only seen when scroll right. Tried adding padding or margin to give extra space next to li to display arrow, but the arrow still hid behind the main div. Also tried add z-index to header, sidebar, main but also not helping.

**Updated**
Forgot to clarify that the arrow I have got is only on sidebar. It should be outside the sidebar which is at the left side of content div. That's why I am trying to get arrow visible on the main div and it ends up being hidden.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove overflow: hidden; from .sidebar

Example here http://jsfiddle.net/u2Lbx4kc/3/

```
.sidebar {
      position: fixed;
      top: 30px;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      z-index: 1000;
      display: block;
      padding: 20px 0;
      margin-right: 20px;    
      background-color: #E5E5E5; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't completely get your question but when the `min-width` is removed the `li` with class arrow seem to appear   http://jsfiddle.net/u2Lbx4kc/1/

Comment: sorry for not being clear on my question. but thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Add classes to `ul` to give it a width

HTML

```
        <ul class="nav nav-sidebar col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <li> <a href="#">1</a>

            </li>
            <li class="active arrow_box"> <a href="#">2</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u2Lbx4kc/4/)

Comment: thanks but I have tried and got the same result but you can see that arrow is still on sidebar and it should be at the left of the content side.